# How do I modify "plist" in command line for React-Native app so it can detect my location? (made with create-react-native-app)

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I want the iOS app to be able to detect my location, to later send it to the server. Attempting to use react-native-geolocation-service.

In command line I did

```
create-react-native-app app-name
cd app-name
```

Did the following as suggested by the terminal because it was unable to start server, no problem:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=5242880
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288
```

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#ios) (pertinent section copy-pasted below) say to modify plist on Xcode and I'd like to do it on command line since that's where I'm working from. If I do need to use Xcode app, how do I integrate it with something I've made on command line? Thanks in advance

*iOS*

*You need to include the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in Info.plist to enable geolocation when using the app. Geolocation is enabled by default when you create a project with react-native init.*

*In order to enable geolocation in the background, you need to include the 'NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription' key in Info.plist and add location as a background mode in the 'Capabilities' tab in Xcode.
If you are using CocoaPods for React Native, make sure to include the RCTGeolocation sub-podspec.*

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [eject](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) your app if you need to add the permission strings to the plist. Ejection will generate the native projects for you, then you can make native changes like your normally would in native development, but you won't be able to run with expo anymore and you'll have to use the CLI or the native IDEs